# Python correctly display .tif file

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I have a .tif file, which Windows Photo Viewer displays as the image below. The file is 32bit float in range [-1, 1].

[image: Original .tif file]

When i open and display the image in a Python Jupyter Notebook, it is shown as:

[image]

Clearly, the displayed image is not as it should be. I have tried normalizing the image, but it does not help.

The (simplified) code:

```
  image = cv2.imread('image.tif', -1)
  #image = cv2.normalize(image, None, alpha = 0, beta = 255, norm_type = cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype = cv2.CV_32F)

  #image = image.astype(np.uint8)

  pyplot.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
  pyplot.axis('off')
  pyplot.show()
```

Also, using `imread` without the -1 flag returns `None`

Comment: Please share your TIFF file, using Dropbox or Google Drive or similar if you would like some assistance. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the files are quite large, around 400MB

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/ lets you add 2GB transiently for passing on to people. The transfer expires when the time runs out; maximum was a few days last I knew.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the link of the file: https://easyupload.io/giejwf
password is: stackoverflow

Comment: It's Windows Photo Viewer that's displaying it incorrectly, clipping off everything below 0. If you want to display it the same way, use `numpy.clip(image, 0.0, 1.0)'.

Comment: No problem. After viewing it with WIndows Photo Viewer, I tried IrfanView and that showed it properly, with all the detail in the areas that used to be just plain black. Then it was kinda obvious what's going on.